# abstraction and interface explanation

Tags: asp.net

could some body explain me abstraction and interface  in asp.net, C# by taking an apprpriate example...pleasse
i am not understanding it for long

Comment: This question is far too broad, and why is this question relating particularly to asp.net?

Comment: Sounds like you're new to OOP. Take a look here: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/03/07/pablo-s-topic-of-the-month-march-solid-principles.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often find the following sample quite illuminating when it comes to explaining this:

<sub>Disclaimer: the code examples are written directly into the text, and may contain errors that I have overseen. Please let me know if you find such errors.</sub>

Let's say you have a database with a Customer table, and in your code you have a customer class:

```
class Customer
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In order to provide a mechanism to get customer data from the database, you need to write some class doing that. This can be placed in something called a *repository*. Now, we don't want our code to rely too much on what exact database we use. It could be SQL server, it could be a text file. So we want an *abstraction layer* shielding the code from this knowledge. All we need to know is what such a repository looks like:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    Customer GetCustomer(int id);
    IEnumerable<Customer> FindCustomers(string beginningOfName);
}
```

We can now implement this interface for the data storage that we use:

```
public class SqlServerCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // code to fetch data and populate Customer objects go here
        }
    }
    // implementations of other members of ICustomerRepository
    // left out to keep code short. Just imagine they are here :)
}
```

Finally, when we want to use this code, we can have a factory create the concrete `ICustomerRepository` implementation to use:

```
public static class RepositoryFactory
{
    public static ICustomerRepository CreateCustomerRepository()
    {
        return new SqlServerCustomerRepository();
    }
}
```

...and in our code where we need the data:

```
ICustomerRepository repository = RepositoryFactory.CreateCustomerRepository();
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = repository.FindCustomers("A");
```

This way, there is no hard coupling between the consuming code, and the particular kind of repository in use (except for in the factory method, *but that is the one and only place where this knowledge exists*). This makes it easy to replace the concrete repository implementation. This is also useful for testing, where you can easily create a mock repository returning hard coded results for given input, so that you can unit test the code that needs data from the repository.

Comment: sir what is IEnumerable here, seems difficult to understand me please elaborate a mre on this..i am novice

Comment: @NovicetoDotNet: `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface that is implemented by virtually all list types (including arrays) in .NET. Basically what it does is that it allows you to loop over the items it contains using a `foreach` loop, and it is also the type around which a lot of LINQ functionality is built.

Answer (score 1):

Well abstract classes and interfaces are not strictly asp.net technic they are OOP concept.

Interface

An interface is like a class but all the methods and properties are abstract. An Interface cannot be instantiated like abstract class. All the methods and properties defined in Interface are by default public and abstract.

Interface generally refers to an abstraction that an entity provides of itself to the outside. Interface can help in separating the methods for external and internal communication without effecting in the way external entities interact with the type.. 
Example: 
If you have `interface IDoSomething { void Do(); }`
The class that implements the interface must provide a body for Do() method e.g.

`class SomeClass : IDoSomething
{
  public void Do()
  {
   //body of the method
  }
}`

The advantage of this is when you make something that need only Do method you pass the interface not the class.

`public static void SomeMethod(IDoSomething obj)
{
  obj.Do();
}`
Now `SomeMethod(IDoSomething obj)` will work with any class that implements `IDoSomething`

Abstract Class

An abstract class is a class with at least one method defined as abstract. This type of class cannot be instantiated. An abstract class can have one or more abstract methods and properties and other methods and properties like normal classes.

The idea is the same but in abstract class you can have methods with implemented logic, fields and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Abstraction**

Abstraction is the process of hiding how the object is working, and its only showing the information of the object the way we can understand it. Means it represent the essential details with out showing ground details. We putting all variables and method in a class which are necessary.

Eg: Employee and Patient.

Company interested to fill about the Employee details like Name, Address, Qualification, DOB, Age, Mobile, Marks, Experience etc

Hospital interested to fill  about the patient details like Name, DOB, Height,  Weight, Age, Address, Mobile, Blood Group etc.

Both Company and hospital interested to fill some common fields like Name, Age, DOB, Address, Mobile etc. So we can create a class which consist of common thing that is called abstract class. This class wont be complete but can inherit by other class.

**Abstract vs Interface** 
You cannot create an object of abstract class , but can make derivations of this.
An abstract class can contain either abstract methods or non abstract methods. Abstract members do not have any implementation in the abstract class, but the same has to be provided in its derived class.

An abstract class can have abstract members as well non abstract members. But in an interface all the members are implicitly abstract and all the members of the interface must override to its derived class.

Defining an abstract class with all the abstract members is similar to defining an interface. i.e we can say an interface is an abstract class with all the abstract members
Classes may inherit from only one base class, so if you want to use abstract classes to provide polymorphism to a group of classes, they must all inherit from that class.
Abstract classes may also provide members that have already been implemented. Therefore, you can ensure a certain amount of identical functionality with an abstract class, but cannot with an interface.

Here are some recommendations to help you to decide whether to use an interface or an abstract class to provide polymorphism for your components.

1). If you anticipate creating multiple versions of your component, create an abstract class. Abstract classes provide a simple and easy way to version your components. By updating the base class, all inheriting classes are automatically updated with the change. Interfaces, on the other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of an interface is required, you must create a whole new interface.

2). If the functionality you are creating will be useful across a wide range of disparate objects, use an interface. Abstract classes should be used primarily for objects that are closely related, whereas interfaces are best suited for providing common functionality to unrelated classes.

3). If you are designing small, concise bits of functionality, use interfaces. If you are designing large functional units, use an abstract class.

4). If you want to provide common, implemented functionality among all implementations of your component, use an abstract class. Abstract classes allow you to partially implement your class, whereas interfaces contain no implementation for any members.